# Offline database for Java

Tags: java, database

I need to store information on a database that can be accessed when the program is not running(persistant storage), but I need it to be offline, without running on a server. I need something like a CSV file, but I'm not a big fan of CSV.

I want to store recipes, so I need 4 or 5 columns. It won't be big, I don't think it's going to be bigger than 10Mb. I meant that has a persistent storage, that the information will be there even if the program isn't running.

Comment: There are many ways to store data, and many kinds of databases. No way to recommend without detailed info from you. What kind of data? Structured or not? One list of items or more? Volume of data? What exactly do you mean by "accessed when program is not running"?

Comment: http://hsqldb.org/ or http://h2database.com/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As I can remember, it is a memoryonly db. I.e. it has no persistent storage.

Comment: Both offer persistent storage

Comment: [This website](http://embedded-databases.com/) lists many alternatives that can satisfy the requirements.

Comment: @BasilBourque I want to store recipes, so I need 4 or 5 columns. It won't be big, I don't think it's going to be bigger than 10Mb. I meant that has a persistent storage, that the information will be there even if the program isn't running.

Comment: @EstebanBal Post clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as Comments. And revise your question to use that word `persist` as that is indeed the precise technical term. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Spreadsheet or FileMaker

For a mere 10 megs of data in a single table (list), consider using a [spreadsheet](http://www.libreoffice.org) or [FileMaker](http://www.filemaker.com) rather than building your own app.

## Database versus File

If your data is churning (being edited, deleted, sorted, and such), then generally best to use a database. A good database helps with the integrity of your data, such as avoiding accidental overwrites from your own sloppy programming or preventing corruption due to crashing while in the middle of writing data. Protecting the integrity of your data (see [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)) is one *big* reason to use a database over writing your own data file such as [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

However, if your data is *not* churning, so you rarely write to it, then writing a CSV may make sense, especially if sharing this data is a primary goal. In such a case, use a library to help with the CSV or Tab-Delimited file such as [Apache CSV](https://commons.apache.org/csv/). Always write to a fresh file before deleting the old file, to avoid losing data.

Any database will store persistent data, to be available the next time your run your app. Some databases also offer an "[In-Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database)" option, where the database lives only in memory, is *not* persistent, and disappears when the database engine is shutdown. But that is never the default, so you would have to go out of your way to lose your data that way.

## H2 + Vaadin + Java

You do not give any requirements or constraints, so there is no way to make a specific recommendation. My own choice would be:

- [*H2* database](http://www.h2database.com/) engine built in pure Java. Can be either embedded in your app or used separately as a database server.
- [*Vaadin* framework](https://vaadin.com/framework) and its [Vaadin Grid](https://vaadin.com/grid) widget to write an web app in pure Java that is automatically rendered in a web-standards HTML5 web browser.

## List of embedded databases

See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database) for a [comparison of a couple dozen embedded database engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database#Comparisons_of_database_storage_engines).

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has Java bindings and there is JDBC connector for it. [Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm).